# Include directives not importing

Tags: c, gcc, time, directive

I've been having this problem multiple times throughout a program I'm currently working on where gcc doesn't recognize a function or file type that I import from a library even though the include directive is clearly at the top of the program with all the others. To get around this I've just been finding similar libraries and using functions from those, but for what I'm trying to do right now none of the libraries I have found are working. Here is my list of directives:

```
#include "oscar.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <utime.h>
#include <malloc.h>
```

I'm currently trying to change the access and modification times in a file. I've tried using utime(), utimes(), futimens() and several other variations and all of them are having the same problem. GCC isn't recognizing many of the functions or file types. For example, I'm trying to use futimens():

```
futimens(m_file_desc, times);
```

but gcc gives the following error

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘futimens’
```

Comment: Could you provide a simple compilable piece of code that we can try?

Comment: What's your platform and glibc version? From the man pages: `Support for futimens() first appeared in glibc 2.6.`

Comment: I'm on a unix virtual machine that's setup for my class by the professor. I'd assume futimens would work because it's actually the function he recommended using

Comment: Type in your bash shell: **locate sys/stat.h** and tell us if it gives you results. Then type **gcc -print-search-dirs** and post results.

Comment: It gave lots of results and here's the second thing:

Comment: install: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/
programs: =/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/bin/

Comment: libraries: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/:/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to need to specify the [feature test macros](http://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros).

From the man page:

```
futimens():
Since glibc 2.10:
_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700 || _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
Before glibc 2.10:
_GNU_SOURCE
```

So, depending on your `glibc` version, you need to either define `_GNU_SOURCE` or `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` with appropriate values.